# ORB Feature Descriptor Official Paper Explanation

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-detection, orb

I was just reading the official paper of ORB from Ethan Rublee [Official Paper](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf) and somewhat I find hard to understand the section of "4.3 Learning Good Binary Features"

I was surfing over the Internet to dig much deep into it and I found the below paragraph. I haven't getting the practical explanation of this. Can any of you explain me this in a simple terms.

"Given a local image patch in size of m × m, and suppose the local window
(i.e., the box filter used in BRIEF) used for intensity test is of size r × r , there are N = (m − r )2 such local windows.

**Each two of them can define an     intensity test, so we have C2N bit features. In the original implementation of ORB, m is set to 31, generating 228,150 binary tests. After removing tests that overlap, we finally have a set of 205,590 candidate bit features. Based on a training set, ORB selects at most 256 bits according to Greedy algorithm.**"

What am getting from the official paper and from the above paragraph is that.

We have a patch size of 31X31 and select a size of 5X5.. We will have N=(31-5)^2 = 676 possible Sub Windows. Am not getting the lines which are marked in bold. What does it mean by removing test that overlap, we get 205,590 bit Features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a small image with size 31x31 (patch) and a small 5x5 window. How many different positions this window can be placed into the image? If you slide it 1 by 1 pixel then it can be placed in (31-5)^2 = 676 different positions, right? Combining only central pixels of 676 windows by 2 elements you have 676!/(2!*(676-2)!) = 228,150 combinations. In case of ORB descriptor they were not interested in slide the window in 1 by 1 pixel, it could be so much noised because of overlap between some windows (they are much near). Then they removed overlapping windows sliding it 5 by 5 pixels and used their central pixels to create binary tests, what reduced total combinations to 205,590.